# How to change width and height of html symbols?

Tags: html, css

I have used &uarrow; and &darrow;. I am able to change its color using css width height or font-weight are not changing.

```css
.percentages {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  text-align: right;
}

.up {
  color: #1abcb0;
}

.stats_arrow {
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<span class="percentages up"><span class="stats_arrow">&uarr;</span> 21.87%</span>
```

I even tried adding display inline-block. no use.

Answer (score 3):

`height` and `width` control the *element* size (and don't apply to elements which as `display: inline` which `span` is by default).

After you add `display: inline-block` you are just adjusting the size of the box the arrow is inside.

The sizes of letters, numbers, emoji, and other characters are controlled by `font-size`.

```css
span {
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* And now the silliness begins */
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: growShrink;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes growShrink {
  from {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  to {
    font-size: 6rem;
  }
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span>&uarr;</span>
```